# JQuery mouseenter() and mouseleave()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseenter, mouseleave

So I have got this demo navigation, which has a small button on the side and when you hover the button, it slides the menu into the window. though I have got the hover working, but now when the mouse leaves, it's still open. how to fix this? I'm pretty new to jQuery by the way

here's the html:

```
<div id="demoNav">
    <button class="open"></button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home Pagina</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">Product Pagina</a></li>
        <li><a href="bestel.html">Bestel Pagina</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$("#demoNav").mouseenter(function(){
       $("#demoNav").animate({marginLeft:'0px'}, 500)
});
```

If you need more info, just tell me, I'll provide more codes.

Comment: this is not the hover on button, this is mouse enter inside the div layout, do a $("#demoNav .open").hover(function(){ //XXXXX code to toggle });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#demoNav").hover(

function () {
    $(this).animate({
        marginLeft: '0px'
    }, 500)
},

function () {
    $(this).animate({
        marginLeft: '50px'
    }, 500)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually told it to hide again.

That said, I'd like to suggest this CSS alternative:

```
#demoNav {
    transition:margin-left 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:margin-left 0.5s ease;
}
#demoNav:hover {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a mouseleave event -

```
$('#demoNav').mouseleave(function(){
   $("#demoNav").animate({marginLeft:'50px'}, 500)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$("#demoNav").hover(function(){
    // do something when mouse hover           
},function(){
    //do some thing when mouseout
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you coded for `mouseenter` but forgot to code for `mouseleave event`

add these lines in jQuery

```
$("#demoNav").mouseleave(function(){
       $("#demoNav").animate({'marginLeft':'50px'}, 500)
});
```

working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EP6wR/

but i will suggest use hover method which is cleaner

```
syntax: $(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

might be this solution works

```
 $('#demoNav .open').on("mouseenter", function(){  $(this).parent().animate({marginLeft:'0px'}, 500); });
 $('#demoNav').on("mouseleave", function(){  $(this).animate({marginLeft:'50px'}, 500); });
```

this will activate the pane on hover of button, but when you leave the div, it'll act again making a left move